# iOS - Sticky section headers in grouped UITableView with custom cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I noticed that when using custom cells in a grouped UITableView, the section headers no longer stay at the top of the view when scrolling down. They just pass out of the view like the rest of the cells. Is there a way to keep the default behavior of the headers while using a custom cell?

Comment: That's how a grouped style table view works. If you want the headers to stay at the top as you scroll, use a plain style table view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grouped` style never stays at the top, `plain` does.